# Can I prevent numpy.array from casting the elements as numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using trying to convert the following to a 2x2 numpy array of interval objects:

```
from interval import interval  # from the "pyinterval" package
import numpy as np

np.array([ 
    [interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])], 
    [interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])]
    ])
```

Unfortunately, this operation casts the intervals as numpy arrays, and gives me a 2x2x1x2 matrix. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening with numpy arrays or matrices?

I was able to get the desired result by populating an empty array first, where jac is a list of lists of intervals:

```
arr = np.empty(shape=(2,2), dtype=interval)

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i][j] = jac[i][j]
```

That being said, I suspect there's a more elegant way to achieve this. Is there a more "pythonic" way to do this?

Comment: What is `interval`?  You can't call a module as if it were a function just like that.

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that, I was using pyinterval; I've corrected by question. Thanks!

Comment: Interval objects apparently look like lists.

Comment: Yes you have to use the allocate and fill.  Sometimes the fill can be done as a whole or by slices.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like numpy will coerce anything `Sequence`-like into a new dimension, even if `np.array` is called with `dtype=object`. You can work around this by directly making an empty array with `dtype=object` and then filling it manually.

```
interval_list = get_intervals()
interval_array = np.ndarray(len(interval_list), dtype=object)

for i, interv in enumerate(interval_list):
   interval_array[i] = interv
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the explicit loop when populating the empty array, you can just assign with `[:]`:

```
class interval(list):
    """I don't have any real interval but this should work."""
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'interval({})'.format(super().__repr__())

import numpy as np

>>> a = np.empty((2, 2), dtype=object)

>>> a[:] = [[interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])], 
...         [interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])]]

>>> a
array([[interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])],
       [interval([1.0, 2.0]), interval([1.0, 2.0])]], dtype=object)
>>> a.shape
(2, 2)
>>> a[0, 0]
interval([1.0, 2.0])
```

Unfortunatly there is no way to explicitly tell `numpy.array` which classes shouldn't be unpacked so you probably need to create the empty array first.

---

On a side note: There is not "interval" dtype for numpy arrays, if it's an unrecognized dtype it will use `object`. Using `dtype=interval` may be confusing for other readers because they might expect an efficient dtype.

Answer (score 0):

With the assign and fill approach it is often possible to assign multiple items from a list.  I have a vague memory that sometimes that doesn't work, but it does work for lists:

```
In [84]: jac = [[[1,2],[1,2]],[[1,2],[1,2]]]
In [85]: arr = np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)
In [86]: arr[...] = jac
In [87]: arr
Out[87]: 
array([[[1, 2], [1, 2]],
       [[1, 2], [1, 2]]], dtype=object)
In [88]: arr[1,0]
Out[88]: [1, 2]
```

p.s. it also works for `jac = [[[[1,2]],[[1,2]]],[[[1,2]],[[1,2]]]]`, which would produce a `(2,2,1,2)` is used as `np.array(jac)`.

Comment: "I have a vague memory that sometimes that doesn't work", only if some implicit broadcasting or unpacking is involved. I've never encountered a problem when the shapes were identical.